# How can we enforce the screen reader to read some text when an event occurs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accessibility, wai-aria

This text is not visible and will be used only for the screen reader.
Example: 
On click of a button, I show a green checkmark png. How can I enforce reader to say something like "Button Clicked".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for your question title is using an `aria-live` region (that's how you get a screen reader to read text), but the description of your problem sounds like a different question.

After you click on the button and get the green checkmark, can you click the button again and the checkmark goes away?  If so, then it's essentially a checkbox.  If you're not using a native checkbox behind the scenes (`<input type="checkbox">`), then you'll need the `aria-checked` attribute (and `role="checkbox"`).  Just toggle `aria-checked` between `true` and `false` (from javascript) and the screen reader will take care of announcing the change.  You need the `role="checkbox"` so that the screen reader also announces that you have a checkbox so the user knows how to interact with it.  You don't have to force any text to be read.

If your button is more like a toggle button that can be pressed in or popped out (like a 'bold' or 'italics' button on a formatting bar), then you'd want to use `aria-pressed` (and `role="button"`) and toggle its value between `true` and `false`.

Keep in mind that if you have a custom checkbox or button, you need to allow the object to be selected with a keyboard in addition to a mouse.  A checkbox should be selectable with the Space key.  A button should allow the Space or Enter key.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#checkbox and https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#button, respectively.

And one final note regarding accessibility, if your green checkmark (PNG) is only used to convey the state of the button, then you're ok.  But if the green color also represents additional information, you'd need another indicator for that additional information.  For example, if a green check meant one thing and a red check meant something else, then color deficient users would not be able to tell the difference between the two.  You'd need an additional icon or text formatting (bold, italics, underline) or some visual cue to convey the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to force most screen readers to start reading from a point is to give it focus. If you make the element focus-able (by giving it a `tabindex`), then explicitly give it focus (`myElement.focus()`), the screen reader should start reading from there.

Note that it will keep reading from there as well, so make sure the flow of your HTML is appropriate for it to continue to read from that point.

Comment: Does it mean, I need to update the aria-label for the button again with the new text?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the button. Just after you trigger the click, and show whatever text you want it to now read, give that element a `tabindex` (if it isn't already an input element) and call `thatElement.focus()` to focus on it. It'll then read whatever it ends up focused on.